# how to install spdlog in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

```
naveen@naveen-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install libspdlog-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libspdlog-dev
naveen@naveen-VirtualBox:~$
```

Comment: Looks like the libspdlog-dev package is only available in 16.04 onwards (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libspdlog-dev). 14.04 end of life is April 2019, so it may be worth considering an upgrade anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [package from 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libspdlog-dev) on your 14.04 LTS manually with commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/spdlog/libspdlog-dev_1.6-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libspdlog-dev_1.6-1_amd64.deb
```

Then use its headers on compilation or launch test examples:

```
cp -ar /usr/share/doc/libspdlog-dev/example ~/libspdlog-example
cd ~/libspdlog-example
gunzip bench.cpp.gz
gunzip example.cpp.gz
make
mkdir logs
./example
./bench
```